# Zerigo DNS gem incompatible with ActiveResource 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, json, format, activeresource

I'm using the zerigo_dns 1.2.0 gem (https://github.com/twilson63/zerigo_dns) and it needs to make a 'request' call using ActiveResource.  It was working fine with Rails 3.0.4 because the default format was XML.  But Rails 3.1.0.rc4 uses JSON as default and was causing problems because Zerigo was expecting the application/xml mime-type.

Anyone knows how I can switch to use XML as default format effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zerigo::DNS::Base inherits from ActiveResource. You should be able to just do

```
Zerigo::DNS::Base.format = :xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with this monkey patch:

```
class Zerigo::DNS::Base
 def self.format
  self._format || ActiveResource::Formats::XmlFormat
 end
end
```